# How to set two local variables with the same value in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, local

This question must be really silly, but I haven't found an answer for it yet.

I'm making a program in C # that dynamically writes a script to run on SQL Server. I declared two variables that receive the values returned from two calls *exec 'procedure_name'*.

In the next block of the script, I want these variables to be set to zero.

How to do this using a **SET**?

would be something like this: 
**SET @ a, @ b = 0?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it via SELECT:

```
SELECT @a = 0, @b = 0
```

With SET you need 2 SET commands:

```
SET @a = 0; SET @b = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Method 1

```
set @a = 0 
set @b = 0
```

Method 2

```
Select @a = 0, @b = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select @a = 0
select @b = 0
```

OR

```
Set @a=0 
Set @b= @a
```

Or

```
set @a = 0 
set @b= 0
```